# Does Hot Restart works in .NET 7 for iOS? (without MAUI)

Tags: xamarin.ios

I'd like to learn to develop iOS apps using just Visual Studio on Windows and an iOS device.
I learned that it's possible to do this if I use MAUI.
Is it possible if I also just use .NET 7 iOS app (no MAUI)?

Also, another question: Can I use the free provisioning to deploy to my iOS device from Visual Studio, without a Mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does Hot Restart work in .NET 7 for iOS? (without MAUI)

According to [Limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/hot-restart#limitations), only iOS apps built with Xamarin.Forms and iOS devices are currently supported.

Also, there are a number of requirements that must be met to use hot restart to deploy an app to a locally connected iOS device on your Windows:

- Visual Studio 2019 version 16.5 or higher
- iTunes (Microsoft Store or 64-bit versions)
- Apple Developer account and paid [Apple Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs) enrollment

> Can I use the free provisioning to deploy to my iOS device from Visual Studio, without a Mac?

I don't think it's possible because you need [Use Xcode to create a signing identity and provisioning profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/free-provisioning?tabs=macos#use-xcode-to-create-a-signing-identity-and-provisioning-profile).

For more details, you can refer to [Free provisioning for Xamarin.iOS apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/free-provisioning?tabs=macos).